# Paging is disabled in custom xsl

Tags: 2013, xslt, paging

I modify the list. And created a xsl file for the xml view. But I can't go to other pages to see the other items.

In normal lists there is arrows and the item numbers on the bottom of the list.

The arrow and the item numbers are disappeared. How can I make them enable again?

Here is my xsl code:

```
<Xsl>

<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
xmlns:msxsl="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xslt"
exclude-result-prefixes="msxsl" xmlns:ddwrt2="urn:frontpage:internal">
<xsl:output method='html' indent='yes'/>
    <xsl:template match='dsQueryResponse' >
<table>
<tr>
<td>Sicil No</td>
<td>Adı</td>
<td>Soyadı</td>
<td>Birimi</td>
<td>Resim</td>
</tr>
<xsl:apply-templates select='Rows/Row'/>

</table>
</xsl:template>     
    <xsl:template match='Row'>
<tr>
<td><xsl:value-of select="@SICIL_NO"></xsl:value-of></td>   
<td><xsl:value-of select="@ADI"></xsl:value-of></td>   
<td><xsl:value-of select="@SOYADI"></xsl:value-of></td>   
<td><xsl:value-of select="@BIRIMI"></xsl:value-of></td>   
<td style="width:60px"><img style="width:60px"><xsl:attribute name="src">http://ahapp/img/image.aspx?s=<xsl:value-of select="@RESIM"></xsl:value-of></xsl:attribute></img></td>   
</tr>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
</Xsl>
```

Answer (score 1):

For rendering pager in List View, the template `pagingButtons` is intended (see vwstyles.xsl)

---

This is the updated version

> Note:
>
> 1)Main.xsl is referenced where base List View templates are defined
>   2)Matching attribute `match="View"` is used to override default View

Xsl property value:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
xmlns:msxsl="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xslt"
xmlns:ddwrt="http://schemas.microsoft.com/WebParts/v2/DataView/runtime"
exclude-result-prefixes="msxsl" xmlns:ddwrt2="urn:frontpage:internal">
<xsl:import href="/_layouts/xsl/main.xsl"/>
  <xsl:output method='html' indent='yes'/>


   <xsl:template name="ViewOverride" mode="RootTemplate" match="View" ddwrt:dvt_mode="root">
    <table width="100%" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="8" border="0">
      <tr>
          <td>Title</td>
          <!--Add another columns here-->
      </tr>
       <xsl:for-each select="$AllRows">
          <xsl:variable name="thisNode" select="."/>
          <tr>
              <td><xsl:value-of select="$thisNode/@Title" /></td>
              <!--Add another fields here-->
          </tr>
       </xsl:for-each>
    </table>
    <xsl:call-template name="pagingButtons" />
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

[image]

For more details, follow this article 
[Overview of XSLT List View Rendering System](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff604024%28v=office.14%29.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

Have you seen this [link](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/a/28538/16290) on SE?

Cite:

> I expect you have "BaseViewID" attribute set to "0" on the "View" element of your custom list definition. You should change this attribute to some other value (in range 1..255) and the problem should vanish then.