# XsltListViewWebPart Specifying Paging

Tags: 2013, xslt-list-view-web-part, paging

I have an `XsltListViewWebPart` for which I programmatically intercept and replace the `<Query>` in it's `XmlDefinition` property. This works fine, and the list displays the correct data based on my queries. I'm running into a problem however, where the arrow buttons for paging through the data no longer work. When clicked, it fades as though the page is trying to do something, but it ultimately just refreshes the same data rather than going to the next page. (I've seen [this](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/28349/how-can-i-use-normal-paging-on-a-custom-view) question, but my `BaseViewID` is already 1).

What I'd like to do is use JavaScript to simply replace the broken arrow buttons with something custom. In order to do this, I need a way to programmatically tell the list (either on the client side via JavaScript, or on the server side via C#) which page of data it should be displaying.

Does anyone know a way to do this? Looking at the `XsltListViewWebPart`, I don't see any properties or XML that specifies which page should be displayed in the current request.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

The `XsltListViewWebPart` looks at query string parameters to help control paging. A good summary of this is [here](http://blog.metrostarsystems.com/2011/03/16/paging-within-list-views-in-sharepoint-2010-using-splistitemcollectionposition/). By setting them via JavaScript on the client side and I was able to page through the data myself.

Note, that for this to work I had to basically rip out the link that SharePoint created in the filter button and apply it myself.