# What is purpose of 'View' with 'BaseViewID' set to '0' in schema.xml of List Definition?

Tags: 2010, list, visual-studio, schema

In Visual Studio 2010 when I create a List Definition the `schemal.xml` file looks something like this:

```
<Views>

  <View BaseViewID="0" Type="HTML" MobileView="TRUE" TabularView="FALSE">
    ....
    <ViewFields>
      <FieldRef Name="LinkTitleNoMenu"></FieldRef>
    </ViewFields>
    ....
  </View>



  <View BaseViewID="1" Type="HTML" WebPartZoneID="Main" DisplayName="$Resources:core,objectiv_schema_mwsidcamlidC24;" DefaultView="TRUE" MobileView="TRUE" MobileDefaultView="TRUE" SetupPath="pages\viewpage.aspx" ImageUrl="/_layouts/images/generic.png" Url="AllItems.aspx">
    ....
    <ViewFields>
      <FieldRef Name="Attachments"></FieldRef>
      <FieldRef Name="LinkTitle"></FieldRef>
    </ViewFields>
    ....
  </View>

</Views>
```

As you can see there are two views one with `BaseViewID="0"` and `BaseViewID="1"`. If I want to show another column in view then I add a `FieldRef` tag in `ViewFields` of view with `BaseViewID="1"`.

What is the purpose of the view with `BaseViewID="0"`? If I add new column to view with `BaseViewID` set to `0` nothing shows happens to default view and there are no additional views shown to me in List UI.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> `BaseViewID 0` is intended for using in views, which are added to home
>   page! Remember, when you're adding a XsltListViewWebPart to a page,
>   you can select to display "Summary view" in webpart properties. This
>   is actually "BaseViewID=0" view.

Source: [How can I use normal paging on a custom view?](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/28349/how-can-i-use-normal-paging-on-a-custom-view/28538#28538)